# Error with the batch login

Tags: batch-file, authentication

i would like to write something like program whitch is reading login and password from fille if they are both corect the program should go to the next point.

```
:rejestracja
cls
set/p "uname=wpisz login : "
set/p "upass=wpisz haslo : "
cls
goto rejestracja2

:haslo
set/p "haslo=wpisz haslo : "
if %haslo%==<<D:\upass.txt goto nowy
if exist %haslo%==<<D:\upass.txt goto start


:rejestracja2
echo %uname%>>D:\uname.txt
echo %upass%>>D:\upass.txt
attrib D:\uname.txt +H
attrib D:\upass.txt +H
cls
goto login

:login 
cls
set /p login="wpisz login :" 
**if {%login%}=={<=D:\uname.txt} goto haslo**
pause > nul
```

i need to fix this line when i putted "**"

Answer (score 0):

You can't read from the file "on the fly".

Read them into a variable first:

```
:login
set /p login="wpisz login :"
set /p Uname=<d:\uname.txt
if "%login%"=="%Uname%" goto ...
```

Same with `:haslo`

In `:rejestracja2` you should use `>` instead of `>>` (overwrite instead of append)